# want a redirection drop-down menu of city wise stores for multi store in opencart

Tags: redirect, opencart, multistore

I am running multi store city wise on Opencart. I want to have a dropdown list of my stores on main store. So, visitors can select their city and they should be redirected to that store and will be saved in cookies. So, next time when they visit my website they should be automatically diverted on their past selection of city.

My store is www.orgoearth.com
multi stores are www.city.orgoearth.com for example www.vadodara.orgoearth.com

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this city based URL redirection in Opencart url handler
 *seo_url.php [path:catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php]*.

In this file, you can set the cookies and check the cookies condition everytime.